# numba.cuda.cudadrv.error.CudaSupportError: Error at driver init:, Quadro M2000, Running Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, dependencies, cuda, gpu

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and have a Quadro M2000 card, running `$ nvidia-smi -L` gives,

`GPU 0: Quadro M2000 (UUID: GPU-df3aa58b-eac2-2d70-3e96-8915f899997e)`

I wanted to use it for python, so I installed `numba` using `$ pip install numba` ,
Checked `nvcc -v` which asked me to install it.

While installing it, I am getting the following errors:

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-cuda-toolkit : Depends: nvidia-profiler (= 10.1.243-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: nvidia-cuda-dev (= 10.1.243-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: nvidia-visual-profiler (= 10.1.243-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: nsight-compute (= 10.1.243-3)
                       Recommends: nsight-systems (= 10.1.243-3)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

The drivers I have installed are the 390 ones, (checked from the nvidia website for M2000 drivers)
I tried to install a few of these packages manually but didn't work out.

So, I refollowed the steps [NVIDIA CUDA Download](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=20.04&target_type=deb_local) to install cuda.

Following this I decided to check `numba`,

```py
>>> import numba
>>> numba.__version__
'0.56.2'
```

Ok, so `numba` got installed properly,

````py
>>> from numba import cuda
>>> print(cuda.gpus)
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/luce/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/cuda/cudadrv/devices.py", line 43, in __str__
    return ', '.join([str(d) for d in self.lst])
  File "/home/luce/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/cuda/cudadrv/devices.py", line 26, in __getattr__
    numdev = driver.get_device_count()
  File "/home/luce/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/cuda/cudadrv/driver.py", line 417, in get_device_count
    self.cuDeviceGetCount(byref(count))
  File "/home/luce/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/cuda/cudadrv/driver.py", line 288, in __getattr__
    raise CudaSupportError("Error at driver init: \n%s:" %
numba.cuda.cudadrv.error.CudaSupportError: Error at driver init: 
Call to cuInit results in UNKNOWN_CUDA_ERROR (803):
````

How can I hope to sort this?